# Create new list from from a single column of existing list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Using Python 2.7

Existing `list`: Columns and same hostname multiple entries:  `xlist`

```
Index([u'id', u'last_checkin', u'name'], dtype='object')

{'last_checkin': <DateTime '20180411T14:28:18' at 7f0639d26d88>, 'id': 1000017017, 'name': 'linux1v'}
{'last_checkin': <DateTime '20180411T17:18:30' at 7f0639d26dd0>, 'id': 1000019428, 'name': 'linux1v'}
{'last_checkin': <DateTime '20180411T17:18:52' at 7f0639d26e18>, 'id': 1000019430, 'name': 'linux1v'}
{'last_checkin': <DateTime '20180411T17:24:55' at 7f0639d26e60>, 'id': 1000019437, 'name': 'linux1v'}
{'last_checkin': <DateTime '20180411T17:21:18' at 7f0639d26ea8>, 'id': 1000019443, 'name': 'linux1v'}
{'last_checkin': <DateTime '20180411T17:30:26' at 7f0639d26ef0>, 'id': 1000019453, 'name': 'linux1v'}
```

New `list`: `zlist`

```
for i in xlist:
  zhostname = i.get('name')
  #print zhostname
  if zhostname not in zlist:
       zlist.append(i)
```

In 1st `list` there are multiple entries for the same host with a different `last_checkin` date and/or `id`. For the new `list` I am trying add to the `list` when hostname does not already exist. But the new `list` seems to be an exact copy of the first `list`. It is like it is not checking for only the hostname in the new list. I do not care about the `last_checkin` date or `id` for either entry.

How does it validate the entry if I am only checking the name of the host?
i.e.:

```
[if zhostname not in zlist:
   zlist.append(i)]
```

So when it looks for the hostname in zlist is it also validating the other columns and sees it is different based on the whole row?

Hopefully this is not clear as mud.

My goal is to have a list with no duplicate hostname entries regardless of `id` or `last_checkin`.

Comment: Sorry this is totally unclear. Do you mean this is a ***pandas dataframe*** column whose contents are a list? (If not, please untag [tag:pandas]). Next, instead of saying *"In 1st list there are multiple entries for the same host with a different last_checkin date... id"*, please **show us some rows of your dataframe, showing the id, last_checkin, name** columns.

Comment: It probably doesn't have anything to do with your actual issue, but it's a really bad idea to name something `list` in your code, since that hides the name of the builtin `list` datatype. It makes your question rather confusing too, since I have no idea when you're saying "list" if you mean the builtin list, or your variable named `list` (which appears not to be a builtin list, but rather a dataframe or something).

Comment: Yea I found an example that use that... I will change it. It was from a Redhat Manual.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that zhostname is just a string so when you compare it to the Index objects using `zhostname not in zlist` the string zhostname will never match the Index's in zlist.

I recommend using a dictionary using the name of the host as the keys.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

```
checkins = dict()
for i in xlist:
    zhostname = i.get('name')
    if zhostname not in checkins:
        checkins[zhostname] = i
```